# hashing through a dataframe as a new colum with some conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hash

I have a table as below and I want to use hash functions to turn the bill_raw_textcolumn into the  hash_column with these conditions:
if order_id is an odd number use SHA256 as hash function on bill_raw_text column
and if order_id is an even number then apply MD5 function on bill_raw_text column data as much as you can find "A" letters in the related data of bill_raw_text column.
[dataframe that im using is shown here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFhyd.jpg) i have poor background of python and descent skills of spark so I think my main issue is coding the function.
so i wrote the following code, but it doesn't work and im not sure what part is wrong.

```
import hashlib
def hashing_f(row):
    if row.order_id %2 == 0:
      text=row.bill_raw_text
      textUtf8=text.encode("utf-8")
      for e in range(text.count('A')):
        hash=hashlib.md5(textUtf8)
        hexa=hash.hexdigest()
      
      return   Row(hexa) 
    else:
      text=row.bill_raw_text
      textUtf8=text.encode("utf-8")
      hash=hashlib.SHA256(textUtf8)
      hexa=hash.hexdigest()
      
      return Row(hexa)
hash_df.rdd.map(hashing_f).toDF().show(truncate=False)()
```

I appreciate any help or idea <3

Answer (score 0):

When you do hash=hashlib.md5(textUtf8), you do always the same thing because textUtf8 does not change. Here is a better solution:

```
def hashing_f(row):
    if row.order_id % 2 == 0:
        hash = row.bill_raw_text.encode()
        for _ in range(hash.count(b'A')):
            hash = hashlib.md5(hash).digest()  # By using digest, you do not need to encode each time
        return Row(hashlib.md5(hash).hexdigest())  # If there is no A, I guess you want to hash it once.
    else:
        return Row(hashlib.sha256(row.bill_raw_text.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: ty for ur answer but it didnt work for me as well. I guess the main issue is exceeding overhead limit. my table has over 2 million rows and today I received the following error. I'll try it on smaller tables later.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded